# DS 160 form : Does refused admission and being sent back to home country count as deportation?

Tags: visas, usa

In 2008 I was refused admission to the us due to a prior misunderstanding of the time difference between germany and california which led to my over 90 day stay by some hours. I was told my visa waiver will come out of suspension after 10 years and i will have no further restrictions due to that. So I needed to get a visa until then.

now on the ds 160 I have to answer the question:
have you ever been removed or deported from any country?

I am not sure if it is yes or no.